# How to configure iReport 3.5 for JasperReports compatibility with lower versions?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Could somebody please tell me how I can configure iReport 3.5 (nb) to use "compatibility mode" and generate report XML for lower versions of JasperReports, ie JasperReports 1.x syntax ? iReport 3.0 had this feature, and now I can't seem to find it in 3.5.  Thank you kindly for any responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> General -> Compatibility

I'm using iReport 3.5 (nb) here and its compatibility only extends back to version 2.0.2.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately our company still has to use JasperReports 1.3.x for various compatibility reasons.

Comment: @AlexMarshall any solution to this? I'm in a similar situation. Have 1.1.1 reports... Malcolm - find a version that goes further back by chance?

Answer (score 1):

in ireport 3.6.2, it is under Tools -> Options -> iReport -> General -> Compatibility